# JavaFX CSS LineChart

Tags: java, javafx

I have JavaFX LineChart and some data with XYChart.Series objects as

```
XYChart.Series<String, Number> series = new XYChart.Series<String, Number>();
series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(key, percent));
lineChart.getData().add(series);
```

I am trying to style the LineChart lines with JavaFX CSS (preferably inline) with not much luck. I have tried numerous things but thought

```
series.getNode().setStyle("-fx-stroke: blue;");
```

should work and it doesn't.

In the [JavaFX CSS Reference LineChart section](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#linechart) it gives this information,

"chart-series-line series < i > default-color < j >"   Where < i > is the index of the series and < j > is the series’ color index

What is the index of a series and the index of a color? 
I have searched StackOverflow, this question does not seem to have been answered, at least not with any working solutions.

Comment: do you have a css file where you handle all the styles or are you setting them directly through FX?

Comment: I do not have a css file, I was attempting to do it all inline, through FX, but I now question if that is wise.

Comment: I think the best decision would be to create a CSS file.

Comment: Whenever I've worked with JavaFX I have always used a CSS file, it was rare that I used inline methods to do it. It also helps with keeping the code organized as well.

Answer (score 0):

The 
series.getNode().setStyle("-fx-stroke: blue;"); must appear after the lineChart.getData().add(series);

```
lineChart.getData().add(series);
series.getNode().setStyle("-fx-stroke: blue;");
```

worked as long as the two lines are in this order. This may have something to do with JavaFX CSS mimicking the DOM, I really don't know though. Ridiculous.